# Equal weight problem

Tags: probability, linear-programming

If I have 3 weighted coins (A,B,C), each with different probability of giving tails: P(At)=0.1,  P(Bt)=0.3 and P(Ct)=0.5. With a maximum of 100 coins, how can I determine the quantity of each type required so that the sum of the probabilities of each type is equal to the individual probabilities of each of the other types?

For example with 2 coins (A, B) where P(At)=0.1 and P(Bt)=0.3, then I would require 75 coins of type A (75*A = 75*0.1 = 7.5) and 25 coins of type B (25*B = 25*0.3 = 7.5).

[image]

Is there a general solution to this problem? What if I have N types coins (A-Z)?

Comment: It occurred to me that the in the equation of a line (y=mx+c) the probability of tails is the slope m. So 2 lines can easily be graphed for 2 coins, and the value for x at the point of intersection is the quantity of type A, and the quantity required of type B is 100-x. However I am having trouble solving it for 3 coins.

Comment: You have $k$ different types of coins and $N\geq k$ coins in total, with probability to get tails $p_1,\dots,p_k$ and we'd like to determine the number of each type of coin $n_1,\dots,n_k$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^k n_i=N$ and $n_ip_i=\mathrm{const.}\forall i\in\{1,\dots,k\}.$ This is not, in general, solvable. Take for instance $k=2,N=3,$ when $(n_1,n_2)$ can take the values $(3,0),(2,1),(1,2),(0,3).$ If you for instance has chosen $p_1,p_2$ to both be irrational, this has no solutions.

Answer (score 2):

If the probabilities of $A$ and $B$ coins are $a$ and $b$ respectively, you need $\frac ba$ times as many $A$ coins as $B$ coins.  If any of these ratios are irrational you are sunk.  Otherwise start with one of the highest probability coin.  Compute how many of all the other coins you need.  Compute the least common multiple of the denominators and multiply by that number.  With your example of $0.1, 0.3, 0.5$, for one of the $0.5$ coins we would need $5$ of the $0.1$s and $\frac 53$ of the $0.3$s, so our result is $15$ of the $0.1$ coins, $5$ of the $0.3$ and $3$ of the $0.5$.  This will give the minimal solution, which may or may not have a total of $100$ coins or less.  If you want a total of exactly $100$ coins, it will work as long as the minimal solution divides into $100$ exactly.  Just multiply by $100$ divided by the total number of coins in the minimal solution.